# Could not find the java executable in default path or ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java

Tags: java, rapidminer

I'm trying to install rapidminer on my Debian 5.2.9-2 kali1 (2019-08-22) i686 GNU/Linux, but i have an issue when running the .sh to install it. I've installed openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre which is the required to run rapidminer but i'm getting this error on the prompt.

````
Could not find the java executable in default path or ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java.
Edit ./RapidMiner-Studio.sh and/or your local startup files.```
````

Any idea?

Comment: $ `echo $JAVA_HOME` output?

Comment: literally nothing @RobertoManfreda

Comment: You need to set your $JAVA_HOME in your .bash_profile!!! https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/setting-java_home

Comment: Look if `/usr/bin/java` exists and eventually run `update-java-alternatives -a`.